# Power BI cumulative count with DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server, powerbi-filters

Here is a table of two rows:

| ItemID | Date1 | Date2 | Category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019-03-18 | 2020-07-31 | A |
| 1 | 2020-10-18 | 2020-07-31 | A |

Cumulatively count the number of unique items by category where Date1 >= Date2

I created a measure (thanks @jprzd) for a column chart:
Measure = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(Table[ItemID]),FILTER(ALLSELECTED(Table),Table[Date1]>=Table[Date2]))

It does not result in the correct cumulative count. I think the above DAX expression is likely in the right direction, but I couldn't figure out where it went wrong.

I'd greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: How about you use the calculated column formula as a measure, and then you use that measure in your chart? Also, create a dimension for the categories and another for the dates. Finally use the columns of these dimensions to filter your chart or as its axis.

Comment: @jprzd Use the formula as a measure certainly made a difference. I'm validating the result while trying to grasp why using a measure instead of a calculated column makes such a difference. Thank you very much for your guidance.

Comment: I see that you have edited the question. And now I don't understand where the problem is. It is difficult to achieve something with an unrepresentative sample (your two-row table). Could you clarify how many tables exist in your model, offer a more representative sample and detail the columns used in your visualization? I will try to review it later.

Comment: @jprzd Thank you very much. With your help and after some further thought, I can better summarize the problem at hand - it's all about a cumulative distinct count of items by category with DAX. These are the most important things I learned from this exercise: 1) Use a measure, 2) need to use ALL, <=Max(...), and && in the formula. The correct formula looks like CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(Table[ItemID]),FILTER(ALL(Table),Table[Date1]<=MAX(Table[Date2] && Category = "A")). I was confused by complex business logics by incorrectly using >. I realize now that I need to use <= independent of biz logic.

Comment: @jprzd Your comment was instrumental in guiding me into the right direction and you indeed answered my question perfectly. I greatly appreciate your help, without it I'd be in dark much longer. Thanks again. –